# How to set Multiple values in else part of a case expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, case, sql-server-2016

I am trying to set multiple values in the else part of a case statement with the below statement.

```
Create TABLE Student(
   id int NOT NULL,
   Fname VARCHAR(25),
   Lname VARCHAR(25),
   AbsentDate VARCHAR(50),
   AbsenceReason VARCHAR(100)
 );

Insert INTO Student(id,Fname,Lname,AbsentDate,AbsenceReason)
values(001,'Jack','P','01-10-2020','Fever'),
(002,'Jack','L',NULL,NULL);

select
CASE WHEN s.AbsentDate IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' Else 'N' As StudentAbsence(Y/N),AbsenceReason='' END 
from Student s`



Expected Result 
  id,Fname,Lname,AbsentDate,AbsenceReason
  001,'Jack','P','01-10-2020','Fever'
  002,'Jack','L',NULL,Blank  --update Null to Blank
```

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Also, `s.AbsentDate IS NULL` is the correct syntax.

Comment: @jarlh using sqlserver-2016

Comment: It can't be done the way you're trying to do.

Comment: Show us some more sample data, and also the expected result. (As formatted text, no images.)

Comment: *case* is an expression that returns a single value. It's not clear what you are trying to do - are you trying to return several columns? It looks like it.

Comment: yes @stu when the StudentAbsence(Y/N) is 'Y' then I have to set the AbsenceReason as 'Fever'.

Comment: *I have to set* - that's a confusing statement, presumably you don't mean set as in "update" - your question needs some sample data and desired results. and you only ever have absence due to Fever? Seems very specific.

Comment: I will reframe my sentence.When the student is not absent then set StudentAbsence To 'N' and update AbsenceReason from NULL to blank.

Comment: Isn't it better to use the CASE statement twice, one for the StudentAbsence(Y/N) column and another one for the AbsenceReason?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
 id,
 Fname,
 Lname,
 CASE WHEN AbsentDate IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END AS [StudentAbsence(Y/N)],
 AbsentDate AS AbsenceDate,
 CASE WHEN AbsentDate IS NULL THEN '' ELSE AbsenceReason END AS AbsenceReason
FROM 
 Student
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=2b2a7b6b5aeef1200f887a3d4449bfa3)